# Почему нежелательно говорить "держите" при вручении товара покупателю?

Tags: грамотная-речь, точное-словоупотребление

Я сама всегда говорю "пожалуйста", когда отдаю отправления клиенту... но коллега говорит "держите". Мне кажется, что это грубовато звучит. И не могу найти слов, чтобы объяснить, что это не совсем корректно. Данный же продавец считал не так давно слово "пожалуй" словом сожаления. Если нет того или иного товара, она говорила: "Пожалуй, этого нет в наличии".

Comment: Интересно, а с этим вопросом что не так, почему его хотят закрыть? Это уж точно не домашнее задание. Мне, к примеру. пришлось хорошо подумать, чтобы предложить свою версию ответа. Возможно, кто-то может дать другой ответ, другое объяснение.

Comment: @Sharon Согласен. Я голосовал за "оставить открытым".

Comment: С вопросом явно "не так" то, что: 1) проблематика не относится к русскому языку, максимум - к этикетно-коммуникативной 2) единичный случай - не предмет для рассмотрения. 3) автор сама прекрасно знает ответ на свой вопрос и хочет получить "официальное" подтверждение, чкго мы дать не можем. ПС Не помню, голосовал ли за закрытие, но если голосовал, то именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы в своих оценках: в речи вашей коллеги действительно допущены **неточности как по стилю, так и по смыслу.** Причем это такие ошибки, которые могут отрицательно сказаться на репутации фирмы.

**1. Держите.**

Слово «держите»  звучит грубо, в общении с клиентами оно недопустимо. А вот вариант «пожалуйста» – это норма, здесь значение «возьмите, пожалуйста».

Но надо объяснить, **почему «держите» – грубая речь.**

Из словаря:
**ДЕРЖАТЬ,** кого-что. 1. Взяв в руки, не давать выпасть, упасть. Д. ребёнка на руках.  Д. зонтик над головой.

В речи встречается слово «держите», которое используется вместо формы «возьмите». В то же время  это слово имеет определенные ограничения. К примеру, его  желательно использовать при общении с  **с хорошо знакомыми людьми**, в других же случаях требуется **осторожность.**

**Почему так?**  Потому что предлагается не просто взять, а "крепко держать, чтобы не уронить или чтобы обратно не взяли". Понять это можно по-разному, в том числе негативно: вы как бы подчеркиваете ценность предмета или выражаете какое-то одолжение. Вот такой **дополнительный смысл** могут почувствовать  посетители  в речи вашей коллеги, а этого допускать нельзя.

Другими словами, слово "держите" в значении "возьмите" приобретает **дополнительный смысл,** при этом он может быть как позитивным, так и негативным. Главное же в том, что **нет нейтрального значения** "возьмите", а только оно и уместно при общении с незнакомыми людьми. А вот слово "пожалуйста" подходит наилучшим образом, оно выражает **вежливое и приятное обхождение,** а это очень важно.

**2. Пожалуй, этого нет в наличии.**

По словарю:
**ПОЖАЛУЙ;** I. в зн. вводн. сл. 1. **Возможно, может быть, вероятно**. Было уже, пожалуй, за полночь.

Итак, сказанная фраза будет понята так: «**Вероятно**, этого нет в наличии, но точно я не знаю». Но разве это правильный ответ?

Почему произошла ошибка?  Слово «пожалуй» похоже на вежливое слово «пожалуйста»,  поэтому кажется, что оно **всегда выражает вежливость.**

В сочетании «пожалуй, нет» мы действительно слышим **вежливый, а не категорический отказ:**  кто-то выражает сомнение, но потом всё-таки отказывает.

Возможно, ваша коллега считает, что  «пожалуй, нет в наличии» – это как раз вежливая фраза, но это не так.

Comment: Как бы подчёркивается? Я вот ничего не подчёркиваю, кроме того, не намекаю, что надо крепко держать, чтобы не уронить или не отобрали... Когда я так говорю, я скорее выражаю дружеское расположение и открытость и просто считаю, что это красивая замена "возьмите" без негативных оттенков смысла. Но согласен, что это по этикету может считаться невежливым с незнакомыми клиентами. Однако был бы рад, если бы мир был свободнее от предрассудков и излишних опасений обидеть. В конечном счёте по интонации видно, есть у человека что-то плохое на уме или нет.

Comment: А так, конечно, можно и безобидным чем-то больно задеть другого, сказав это с соответствующими мыслями, интонациями и взглядом.

Comment: Артем, вы меня не совсем поняли, поэтому я, пожалуй, добавлю в ответ немного текста. Я и раньше хотела это сделать, а вот теперь вижу, что это необходимо. А вам вот что хочу сказать.Во-первых, почему вы не дает ответ. Ваша точка зрения интересна, она имеет право на самостоятельную позицию. Во-вторых, мы не совсем противоположны с вами. Вот вы употребляет слово "выражаю", а это дополнительная коннотация. Она может быть разной, негативной и позитивной, главное же, слово "держите" здесь не является нейтральным, а это уже плохо.

Comment: Незнакомые люди могут понять вас по-разному,  да и выражать  по отношению к клиентам нужно только вежливость и приятное обхождение, а вовсе не дружеское расположение, которое можно принять  за фамильярность. Это же касается и интонации - только вежливость, только любезность,  и ничего больше.

Comment: Вот это меня и расстраивает: даже если клиент понравился, нельзя себе позволить ни малейшей вольности — только любезность и искусственная улыбка. Раньше в мире было меньше этого, думаю. Те же купцы, наверно, могли позволить себе гораздо больше внутренней свободы.

Comment: А что касается ответа, я думаю, автору не очень интересно, что я думаю о сложившихся нормах. Я высказываю свои мысли о них, а вы констатируете их и объясняете, почему обратное считается невежливым. Так что мне кажется, что автору не очень важно, какими бы я хотел видеть отношения и нормы общения, как бы хотел их изменить. А что ситуация такая, какой вы её описали, я полностью согласен. Не до конца согласен только с вашей трактовкой восприятия смысла слова.

Comment: Купцы знали, как и с кем разговаривать. По отношению  к чиновным людям они не стали бы проявлять дружескую фамильярность. Вот и вы делайте так же. Что касается важности вашего ответа, то вы неправы.  Автор вопроса в его изначальной форме просил помочь отучить коллегу от неправильной речи. А отучить можно только одним способом - убедить  в том, что ее речь не только неправильна, но еще и неуместна при общении с клиентами, что она наносит ущерб фирме. Вот и убедите ее в этом или, наоборот, скажите, что всё нормально, пусть себе так говорит. Вы меня в этом хотели поправить?

Comment: Кстати, о позитивной коннотации. Когда вы вручаете  знакомым подарок и говорите "вот, держи (те)", вы уверены, что вас правильно понимают?  Что вы выражаете? Может быть, подчеркиваете торжественность момента или ценность именно вашего подарка, а это нескромно. Как хотите, но звучит грубовато.  Просто не все это слышат.

Comment: Нет, я поправлять не хотел.)) Не хочу давать такой ответ, который поддержит горстка людей. Да я и не считаю, что так и надо говорить. Приходиться подстраиваться под существующие правила и, если нарушать их, то не совсем вызывающе. Теперь отвечу на последний комментарий. Подарок я вручать со словами "держи" не стану. Скажу просто "это тебе" или "вот это вам". А "держи" или "лови" (например, когда ссылку отправляю) скажу, когда от меня уже ждут чего-то.

Comment: Не понимаю, о какой горстке людей вы говорите? Вы слышали, чтобы в магазине кто-нибудь когда-нибудь сказал покупателю "держите". Все продавцы вышколенные, только и слышно: благодарим за покупку, приходите еще. Никто не хочет терять работу. И здесь речевой этикет нарушали ненамеренно, по незнанию, так почему же не помочь людям разобраться. А когда говорят "лови-держи ссылку" (как мяч), то вся  ситуация носит переносный характер, это совсем другое дело.

Comment: *Никто не хочет терять работу.* Да, и поэтому все говорят не только вежливо, но и как роботы, все одинаково. Нет, я и не предлагаю им на кассах говорить "держите".

Answer (score 0):

"Пожалуй, этого нет в наличии" звучит как-то неуместно, на мой вкус.

*Пожалуй* связано не только с "наверное", но и с повелительным наклонением. В словаре, на мой взгляд, недостаточно точное определение "пожалуй"="наверное". Более точное определение, на мой взгляд, "пожалуй"="пускай наверное".

*Было уже, пожалуй, за полночь = Было уже, пускай наверное, за полночь.*

*Я, пожалуй, откажу ему = Я, пускай наверное, откажу ему.*

А теперь представьте продавца, который говорит вам: "Пускай этого нет в наличии"...

Даже менее замысловатое "Похоже, этого нет в наличии" предполагает предшествующие действия продавца для проверки этого самого наличия. Если же никаких действий не было, а есть только слова, то уместно говорить что-то типа:

> Боюсь/наверное/к сожалению/возможно/вероятно/по-моему, этого нет в наличии.